# Извлечение элемента массива из выражения

Tags: массивы, php

Если некоторый метод возвращаем массив, можно ли (как в некоторых ЯП) в этой же цепочке операций извлечь нужный элемент?

Например, так **не** работает:

```
$element = $mysqli->query($query)->fetch_row()[2];
```

Есть ли такая возможность в `php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такая возможность появилась в PHP версии 5.4, "Array dereferencing support".

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, для этого создается доп.функция?

    function foo() {
     return array(1, 2, 3);
    }

    echo foo()[0];

А все, понял, это  для примера.

Comment: @Deus нет, это как пример.

Comment: Ну, я почитал в новой версии много из javascript. Как то:

    $newArray = [1,2,3];